# I can't access the internet through my raspberry pi when connected through ssh

Tags: networking, ethernet, apt, dns

### Proof of the error

When I try ping `8.8.8.8` through SSH I get this:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2007ms
```

---

### What I have tried

My **/etc/resolv.conf** looks like this:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

My **/etc/network/interfaces** looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static

address 31.51.249.21
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 31.51.249.18
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

---

### My network

When I type the command **ifconfig -a**:

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr b8:15:qd:32:a5:6c
inet addr:31.51.249.21 Bcast:31.51.249.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:330247 errors:0 dropped:46340 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:63355 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:47649638 (45.4 MiB) TX bytes:14773496 (14.0 MiB)

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:1309 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:1309 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:146798 (143.3 KiB) TX bytes:146798 (143.3 KiB)
```

When I type the command **route -n**:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         31.51.249.18    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
31.51.249.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

---

Please help me with what might be the cause of this. It is preventing me from being able to install anything onto my raspberry! I would be so grateful for any help on why this might be happening!

---

## answer to framp:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: 1) Are you sure .18 is the gateway? Usually .1 is used as the gateway in a subnet. 2) Do you have an active firewall? What's the result of sudo iptables -L -vn

Comment: I will answer in an edit ^^

Comment: Your Pi is connected directly to the internet without an intervening router?   What does ping 31.5.249.18 return?

Comment: And in answer to part one - Yes you can see my output of **route -n** which shows the gateway

Comment: `64 bytes from 31.51.249.18: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=1.30 ms ...` aka it works

Comment: Good.   Next, try traceroute 8.8.8.8

Comment: `traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254)  1.152 ms  2.978 ms  2.763 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
`

Comment: Do you know what 192.168.1.254 is?  A router?   If so, are there other devices connected to it, and what are their network configurations?   Perhaps adding more detail to the question about your connectivity would help.   What is the Pi connected to?  What other devices are connected the same way?

Comment: Yes it is a router! I can ping 8.8.8.8 successfully from the router! I have tried turning off the firewall on the hub but still no luck... I am pretty lost at what to do!

Comment: First (if you haven't), double check your router and Pi are connected to the internet, and your IP is correct. If that's all good, try moving your Pi over to a friendly neighbour's house, or maybe your office. Plug it in there, and try again. If that works, I'd recommend replacing your router and/or modem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're connected to a router at 192.168.1.254.

Try

```
  address 192.168.1.xxx  (choose an address that's not in use)
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.254
```

Or probably better, use dhcp to assign an IP by changing "`static`" to "`dhcp`" on the "`iface eth0 inet`" line, and delete the `address`, `netmask`, and `gateway` directives.

Comment: I have now lost my connection through ssh and I am 200 miles away from the pi... Thanks for your help though! I will try when I get home in a month or so

Comment: Ouch, so sorry!  Might have been a bit more conservative in how to test that had we known.   I'm used to mine being in the next room if I have to reset or make an emergency change.

Comment: No worries my fault! I just changed the gateway to what you said. As the gateway before was the static ip I had set on my hub! I am not quite sure why that has caused everything to mess up, as the port forwarding on my hub was linked to the RP device and its ip `address` (as can be seen above)? I don't see why the gateway being the static one is necessary?

Comment: I have remote connected to a computer on my network at home now!! So I can ssh locally but for some reason I cannot connect to it!! My hub says the pi is connected and that it has the ip `31.51.249.21` but it is not connecting!!! I am so confused!! Why would have the gateway changed that?!

Comment: This sucks... It is impossible isn't it!! As it is not a static ip anymore?

Comment: Right I am back online!! (Still through SSH) If you can help me?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the network setup. What internet connection, hubs, routers, gateways, what conencts to what ans how, ect.

Comment: I have reset everything now! As I am back home. The ip is now set to dhcp what should I now do to access it through ssh?